# SQL Query with 2 unrelated WHERE criteria

Tags: sql

I'm beginner in SQL, please help me with this. 
I have 2 tables:

```
**Assessment_Schedule** (Use to lookup Session number) <br>
**UnitCode | AssessmentNumber | Session_Start | Session_Due**
    Unit 1 | AN1              | Session 1     | Session 3   |
    Unit 1 | AN2              | **Session 2   | Session 2** |
    Unit 1 | AN3              | Session 5     | Session 9   |
    Unit 2 | AN1              | Session 6     | Session 8   |
    Unit 2 | AN2              | **Session 7   | Session 7** |
    Unit 2 | AN3              | Session 8     | Session 10  |

**-> Class_SessionDate <br>**
**ClassCode | SessionNumber | SessionDate **
     Class1 | Session 1     | 01/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 2     | 04/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 3     | 08/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 4     | 12/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 5     | 16/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 6     | 20/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 7     | 24/01/17 | 
     Class1 | Session 8     | 28/01/17 |
```

What I want to achieve in the result is

```
**ClassCode | UnitCode | AssessmentNumber | Ass_StartDate | Ass_DueDate     **
     Class1 | Unit 1   | AN1              | 01/01/17      | 08/01/17 
     Class1 | Unit 1   | AN2              | 04/01/17      | 04/01/17 
     Class1 | Unit 1   | AN3              | 16/01/17      | 01/02/17 
     Class1 | Unit 2   | AN1              | 20/01/17      | 28/01/17 
     Class1 | Unit 2   | AN2              | 24/01/17      | 24/01/17 
     Class1 | Unit 2   | AN3              | 28/01/17      | 10/02/17
```

I've achieved so far is getting the Ass_StartDate using WHERE criteria, the Ass_DueDate just show the same value as Ass_StartDate. 
 
Then when I put in "And WHERE" for Ass_DueDate, only 2 results generated which are:

```
Class1 | Unit 1 | AN2 | 04/01/17 | 04/01/17
Class1 | Unit 2 | AN2 | 24/01/17 | 24/01/17
```

Please help me with this. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you include the query you've tried in its entirety? `AND WHERE` sounds like it would generate a syntax error. If you mean `WHERE` something `AND` something else, it would be helpful to see *exactly* what you're looking at. Also, just a thought, you might want to work on your abbreviations.

Comment: Hi Bob, Thanks for editing my post which makes it much clearer.  This is my query  **SELECT Class_SessionDate.ClassCode, Assessment_Schedule.UnitCode, Assessment_Schedule.AssessmentNumber, Class_SessionDate as Ass_StartDate, Class_SessionDate as Ass_DueDate
FROM Assessment_Schedule, Class_SessionDate,
WHERE Assessment_Schedule.Session_Start = Class_SessionNumber AND Assessment_Schedule.Session_End = Class_SessionNumber ** I think i need to use Union? Sorry I'm yet to be familiar with Stackoverflow formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN statement
something like

```
SELECT T2.ClassCode, T1.UnitCode, T1.AssessmentNumber, (SELECT SessionDate FROM Table1 WHERE SessionNumber = T1.Session_Start), (SELECT SessionDate FROM 

Table1 WHERE SessionNumber = T1.Session_Due)

FROM Your_tables
```

Comment: Thank you so much Asmgx, you're genius, that's all I can say :). Combined with GROUP BY, it works like magic :D . Again. Thank you!!!